# Updating an array of an array in mongoDB using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to update a document in my mongoDB which contains nested array.
The situation is as follows:

I have a newsItem model, which can contain a poll object. this poll object has: title, totalVotes and options. option is an array of objects, these object contain: optionName and optionVotes. In each of these objects. the optionVotes is an array which contains the Id's of the users who voted on them. (because i want to track who voted on what and how many i want to prevent voting twice)

So it should look something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb7487727430319f5c18495"),
    "poll" : {
        "totalVotes" : 0,
        "title" : "test",
        "options" : [ 
            {
                "optionName" : "Burgers",
                "optionVotes" : []
            }, 
            {
                "optionName" : "Pizza",
                "optionVotes" : []
            }, 
            {
                "optionName" : "Fish",
                "optionVotes" : []
            }, 
            {
                "optionName" : "BBQ",
                "optionVotes" : []
            }, 
            {
                "optionName" : "Soup",
                "optionVotes" : []
            }, 
            {
                "optionName" : "Pasta",
                "optionVotes" : []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What i am trying to do now is, whenever the api route /news/votes/:id gets called, it will update the newsitem with :id and put the users id in the given voteoption. (which is in the body)
So in the request i have: user id and the voted optionName

This is what i got at the moment which is not working for me:

```
exports.vote = (req, res) => {
    News.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }).exec((err, newsItem) => {
        let tempItem = newsItem
        for (let i = 0; i < tempItem.poll.options.length; i++) {
            if (tempItem.poll.options[i].optionName === req.body.optionName) {
                tempItem.poll.options[i].optionVotes.push(req.user._id)
            }
        }
        console.log(tempItem.poll.options[0])
        tempItem.save(err => {
            if (!err) {
                return res.status(200).send()
            }
        })
    })
}
```

the weird thing is, when i do for example:

tempitem.poll.title = 'new title'
tempitem.save()

then the title does get updated in the databank!
the console.log in the code does output the correct object though..

I also tried using the more standard way of:

```
findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.param.id }, {$addToSet: {.....}}).exec(...)
```

But that way i have actually no clue how to get an object with a specific key from an array and then update a part of that object.

2 other options i was thinking about:

- Extracting the whole poll object to another document and then using a
  reference in the newsItem.. but that is not solving the problem
  either (also feels to SQL)
- Not putting the array of voted users in each voteoption but just make
  a user array of all people who voted. --> disadvantage: i can't look
  up who voted on what..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not really utilizing findOneAndUpdate (since you are not providing the actual update) you can simply use `findOne` and try something like this:

```
exports.vote = (req, res) => {
    News.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }).exec(err, tempItem) => {
        let option = tempItem.poll.options.find(({optionName}) => optionName == req.body.optionName)
        option.optionVotes.push(req.user._id)
        console.log(option)

        tempItem.save(err => {
            if (!err) {
                return res.status(200).send()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

That would be one way to do it. I think the best way would be to utilize the `update` portion and use `findOneAndUpdate` with the update object passed in.

Like so:

```
findOneAndUpdate({ 
   _id: req.param.id, 'poll.options.optionName': req.body.optionName
}, 
{ $addToSet: 
  { 'poll.options.$.optionVotes': req.user._id }
}).exec(...)
```

Comment: This works perfectly! i opted to use the 2nd option, because it felt more intuitive together with my other code. I now better understand how to query by seeing your example. Thanks!